# Is there a database with pictures of tooth shade determination procedures?

Tags: cracked-broken-tooth, teeth-alignment, periodontitis

I'm starting to work with image processing trying to understand better tooth shade determination with VITA Classical A1-D4 scales.

Is there any image DB with such images? I found a lot of medical and dental databases but none of them had anything related with that.

What I am exactly looking for? Images of a mouth with all or with a missing teeth, in which you can also see the tooth scale with the correct shade, like A3 or B2 for example.

If I did not find it I am willing to create one to leave it available for future studies. So I am also looking for volunteers.

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, recruiting volunteers isn't something that's done here.

Comment: Just as a pointer for anyone looking to do this. The problem with computerised images for shade matching is that you will need to make sure that monitors on computers being used for this purpose are calibrated for correct colour matching. Different makes and models can be very different in their colour displays. You would also need to make sure the image shades were matched on calibrated monitors.

Comment: Though it's a good idea, however have you checked various CAD CAM shade matching technologies eg. Itero? Wherein one can scan the patient's mouth with an intraoral scanner and the information will automatically get transferred to the computer and the computer will show which tooth colour shade will be appropriate based on adjacent colours of teeth and it will mill the restoration crown also of that colour